# Understanding DOMAIN ERROR in APL: copy/pasting results in two steps works

Tags: apl

I have experimented with APL but ran into a DOMAIN ERROR, which I could not understand.

Here is what I tried in gnu-apl:

```
      isPrime ← {2=⍴(0=(⍳⍵)|⍵)/⍳⍵}
      (isPrime¨ ⍳20) / ⍳20
 DOMAIN ERROR
      (isPrime¨⍳20)/⍳20
      ^             ^
```

To my surprise when I just evaluated the call to isPrime, and copied the resulting array, the DOMAIN ERROR goes away:

```
      (isPrime¨ ⍳20)

 0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
```

```
      0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0 / ⍳20
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
```

... but assigning it to a variable does not work either:

```
      ps ← (isPrime¨ ⍳20)
      ps / ⍳20
DOMAIN ERROR
      ps/⍳20
      ^  ^
```

Now I'm quite confused. I would have expected that all three ways should have worked identically:

1. calling the function directly
2. calling it and copy/pasting its result
3. using a temporary variable instead of copy/paste.

I also double-checked with the browser-based [ngn/apl interpreter](https://ngn.github.io/apl/web/index.html). I had to change the code a little, as itoa starts counting from 0. However, the DOMAIN ERROR is identical:

```
isPrime ← {2=⍴(0=(1+⍳⍵)|⍵)/(1+⍳⍵)}
```

⍝ (isPrime¨ (1+⍳20)) / (1+⍳20)
⍝ DOMAIN ERROR

isPrime¨ (1+⍳20)
⍝ 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0

ps ← isPrime¨ (1+⍳20)
⍝ ps / (1+⍳20)
⍝ DOMAIN ERROR

0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 / (1+⍳20)
⍝ 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19

As two different implementations show the same behavior, I am quite certain the mistake is on my side. Unfortunately, my understanding of APL is very limited.

Comment: Extra spaces between numbers in the answer may be an indication that some extra nesting is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each of the elements in the return from isPrime is a one-element vector in itself - and reduction requires a simlpe vector of booleans.

```
⍴¨isPrime¨⍳20
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
      (∊isPrime¨⍳20)/⍳20
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
```

(I'm not sure if this will work in GNU APL. The monadic `∊` is "enlist" which will transform the nested vector into a simple one...)

To avoid the problem, you should make sure that the result of your function is a scalar. While it looks like that, you compare a scalar (`2`) against a 1-element vector (the ⍴) which in turn makes it a vector. So if you convert that one-elem vector into a scalar, your function works as intended:

```
isPrime ← {2=⍬⍴⍴(0=(1+⍳⍵)|⍵)/(1+⍳⍵)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't executed you code, but I'd suspect that each of the elements in the return from isPrime is a vector in itself.